# What do the blinking menu entries in X-COM: EU mean?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In some menus in X-COM there are sometimes certain entries blinking. I have seen this in the mission selection and in the equipment factory screen. What does it mean? Are these recommended choices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically means that the person supervising that division has something they want to call to your attention. It can mean new research options or a plot point coming up, or an urgent mission request from the Council...

Answer (score 0):

It can also mean that the name of the item is scrolling (explination: because it's too long to fit in the text field), so it scrolls to the end, stops, then fades out and back in at the beginning of the title, to scroll again...

I noticed this yesterday lol